# JS error in contacts list: d.doscroll("left")

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site that loads contacts from a query and presents them in drop downs on the page, but I recently encountered a problem when loading the page in Internet Explorer (I think 8, maybe 7). When I open the page, the contacts do not load; a user has to refresh the page 3-5 times before they load. However, if a user accesses the site on chrome, it loads first try.

When I ran the IE debugger, I received this error message:

[image]

I have other js on the site that still works fine, so I do not believe it is an IE error. Help?

Comment: Make sure the content of the page has fully loaded before you call your function

Comment: Paul Irish mentions this exact code piece [here](https://youtu.be/i_qE1iAmjFg). It was originally an idea by [Diego Perini](http://javascript.nwbox.com/IEContentLoaded/)

Comment: @Diego can I get like a TLDR to help my specific situation? Don't have time to watch an hour long video at the moment. Thanks for sharing though!

Comment: It's only for 5min, I linked to that specific portion of the video

Comment: It starts at the beginning when I click your link. What time did it start at?

Comment: Hm, the link works for me. Anyways, the relevant part starts at 21:30